# How do I separate coefficients from their variables in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, my question involves a little more than the title suggests. I am writing a program to calculate the molar mass of chemical compounds. So far I have it working for chemical compounds with no more than one of each element like NaCl, but I need it to be able to calculate the mass of something like H2O. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import re
atomic_wt = {'Na':22.99, 'Cl':35.45, 'H':1.008, 'O':16}
input = raw_input()
elementList = (re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', input))
wt_list = []

for element in elementList:
    elem_wt = atomic_wt[element]
    wt_list.append(elem_wt)

#    print elem_wt

print "%sg" % sum(wt_list)
```

When I enter something like H2O it comes back with an error saying that H2 is not in my dictionary. How do you suggest I separate the H from the 2? And, how do you suggest I tell it to multiply the value of the elements by their coefficients before it does the adding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made certain modification in your code to separate out coefficients from the elements that you are taking out using regex.

```
import re
atomic_wt = {'Na':22.99, 'Cl':35.45, 'H':1.008, 'O':16}
input = raw_input()
elementList = (re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', input))
wt_list = []

for element_withcoeff in elementList:
    #Separate the coefficients
    coeffList = re.findall(r'\d+', element_withcoeff)
    if len(coeffList) < 1:
        coeff = 1 #If no coefficent is defined use 1 as default 
    else:
        coeff = int(coeffList[0])

    #Separate the element name for dictionary lookup
    element = filter(lambda c: not c.isdigit(), element_withcoeff)
    print coeff, element

    #Calculate using coeff
    elem_wt = coeff * atomic_wt[element]
    wt_list.append(elem_wt)

print "%sg" % sum(wt_list)
```

Note: I am not a chemistry student so make sure the logic for calculating the molar mass id correct or not.

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect. Helped a lot :)